# Empty response on Time line notification

Tags: java, google-mirror-api, google-glass

I am using the Java quick start app to learn about the mirror api. I deployed it to aws and am able to successfully interact with it. I have updated the MirrorClient to set the callbackURL to route through the proxy (https://mirrornotifications.Appspot.com/forward?url=http://{myurl}/notify) and I do get notifications but the response is always empty. It is a custom menu item I am trying to process, so I'm wondering if I am missing something basic in constructing the Menu Item. The relevant code is below.

```
List<MenuValue> menuValues = new ArrayList<MenuValue>();
MenuValue defaultValue = new MenuValue();
defaultValue.setDisplayName("Find");
defaultValue.setState("DEFAULT");
menuValues.add(defaultValue); 

MenuItem nearMe = new MenuItem();
nearMe.setId("nearMe");
nearMe.setAction("CUSTOM");
nearMe.setValues(menuValues);
searchNearMeMenuList.add(nearMe);

TimelineItem timelineSearchNearMe = new TimelineItem();
timelineSearchNearMe.setText("Search near me");
timelineSearchNearMe.setIsBundleCover(false);
timelineSearchNearMe.setBundleId("mySearch");
timelineSearchNearMe.setSourceItemId("FIND_NEAR_ME");
timelineSearchNearMe.setMenuItems(searchNearMeMenuList);
timelineSearchNearMe.setNotification(new NotificationConfig().setLevel("DEFAULT"));
```

Would it be related to the fact that I'm deployed on aws and not app engine? Thanks in advance for any help.

Updated with GET response.

```
{
"kind": "mirror#timelineItem",
"id": "9944f290-89b5-46b0-aa7d-2a06623a5d07",
"sourceItemId": "FIND_NEAR_ME",
"bundleId": "mySearch",
"isBundleCover": false,
"selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/mirror/v1/timeline/9944f290-89b5-46b0-aa7d-2a06623a5d07",
"created": "2013-08-06T16:01:42.886Z",
"updated": "2013-08-06T16:01:42.886Z",
"etag": "\"ZECOuWdXUAqVdpmYErDm2-91GmY/01TB49uN8ZW2c8MYSuyXCySS-KE\"",
"text": "Search near me",
"speakableText": "This will find stores near you",
"menuItems": [
    {
        "id": "nearMe",
        "action": "CUSTOM",
        "values": [
            {
                "state": "DEFAULT",
                "displayName": "Find"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"notification": {
    "level": "DEFAULT"
}
}
```

Comment: AWS should be fine :)  Can you please share a few more details, though? Can you do a GET on the timeline item that you've inserted and share the json representation? Also, the notification is in the request (not the response). Can you share the request body for the notification that's delivered?

Comment: The GET for the timeline item is the following:

Comment: {"kind":"mirror#timelineItem","id":"9944f290-89b5-46b0-aa7d-2a06623a5d07","sourceItemId":"NEARME","bundleId": "search","isBundleCover": false,"selfLink":"https://www.googleapis.com/mirror/v1/timeline/9944f290-89b5-46b0-aa7d-2a06623a5d07","created":"2013-08-06T16:01:42.886Z","updated": "2013-08-06T16:01:42.886Z","etag": "\"ZECOuWdXUAqVdpmYErDm2-91GmY/01TB49uN8ZW2c8MYSuyXCySS-KE\"","text":"Search near me","speakableText":"This will find stores near you","menuItems": [{"id": "nearMe","action": "CUSTOM","values": [{"state":"DEFAULT","displayName":"Find"}]}],"notification": {"level": "DEFAULT"}}

Comment: Can you edit your original question and add it there for improved readability? =)

Comment: Sure thing. The character limit made it so I had to make it impossible to read :). Thank you for the help!

Comment: After some remote debugging, it turns out that the check for while (notificationReader.ready()) was returning false. I tried a few different loop constructs but netted out using a Scanner. Have to do more testing but that has at least allowed me to process notication and location updates for now.

Comment: Can you post the code you ended up using with scanner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"blank" notifications can be a bit of a tricky issue. Here are some troubleshooting steps:

1. Double check the JSON for your timeline item. Confirm that it contains values in `menuItems`. (already done)
2. Double check the code for your notification handler to make sure that it's pulling data from the request, rather than the response, which will be blank until you define it.
3. Use an HTTP tool like command line `curl` to simulate a notification, like this one copied from the [docs](https://developers.google.com/glass/subscriptions#custom_menu_item_selected).

   ```
   {
     "collection": "timeline",
     "itemId": "3hidvm0xez6r8_dacdb3103b8b604_h8rpllg",
     "operation": "UPDATE",
     "userToken": "harold_penguin",
     "userActions": [
       {
         "type": "CUSTOM",
         "payload": "PING"
       }
     ]
   }
   ```

   With a command like this:

   ```
   $ curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d@payload.json http://{myurl}/notify
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue of blank notifications also.  I found closing the response before reading request caused issue that request.inputStream was already closed.  MOving this

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
Writer writer = response.getWriter();
writer.append("OK");
writer.close();
```

To after I fully read in request notification into a String solved the issue.